# Euphemism for the English word for human excrement (faeces in Latin)

Tags: single-word-requests, euphemisms

In German, we call the result of one particular dump as well as the doing it itself

> sein Geschäft machen (to do a deal/business)

This is common and fit for print. Is there something similar in English that I could use in the following sentence

> After his morning *_* ,...

Or what other ways are there to express that without being vulgar or too technical?

Comment: I think the type of expression you’re looking for is a _euphemism_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet... Yap, you're right. I changed it

Comment: I have a few suggestions but it depends on audience.  Can it be humorous at all?

Comment: @Ste... definitely... as long as you can say it at lunch without offending the elderly by the mere words (content may offend them :)

Comment: Germans seem to have a fascination with that particular bodily function which English-speakers don't really have an equivalent for. Its little-remarked upon (perhaps because in English this is something we'd prefer to pretend never happens), but once someone pointed it out to me, I started seeing it a lot.

Comment: @T.E.D.... we do... it is our main domain for swears...not sex, not family, not god but pooh

Comment: A lot of English speakers are going to see "pooh" and get confused at first, thinking of [Winnie the Pooh, also known as Pooh Bear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnie-the-Pooh).  What you're asking about doesn't have the 'h' on the end, although they are pronounced the same:  Poo.

Comment: There are sooo many euphemisms for this that a whole section of the Profanisaurus is dedicated to it! http://www.viz.co.uk/profanisaurus.html

Comment: To "drop the kids off at the pool" is my personal favourite.

Comment: While not synonymous with *dumping*, one could say (by way of completing *your* phrase) " *After his morning* **ablutions** *, ...* "

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps I think "ablution" refers to the act of washing oneself, so anything from washing your face in the morning to taking a shower would constitute "morning ablutions". The OP is looking for a euphemism for moving one's bowels.

Comment: Does the reader need to know what the character did in the bathroom? Can you find some general term for morning bathroom routine, akin to the French expression *faire ses toilette*, as in toiletries, not toilet bowl?

Comment: Poo is already euphemism. It is baby talk. As in German the correct English word is “shit” (Sheiße). But it appears only acceptable to use this as a swear word.

Comment: Why was it found necessary to censor the salient word in a question title which had (until the change) existed for over 6 years?

Comment: @RosieF You raise an excellent point. If you might be so kind, please raise the matter on our meta for the community to consider.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know of any nouns that fit your proposed phrase, but there are a few verbal phrases that might suit your purposes.

American speakers (and possibly other English speakers) use the euphemism of [*relieving oneself*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/relieve+oneself). So, in your example, you might say:

> In the morning, after he relieved himself...

Like the German phrase you mention, English also includes the euphemism [*to do one's business*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/do+one%27s+business), but it usually carries an implication of immaturity toward the object of the expression:

> **do one's business**, (usually of an animal or child) to defecate or urinate: *housebreaking a puppy to do his business outdoors*.

So we might say,

> After my dog Sparky did his business on his favorite tree, we returned home.

Comment: Not to be crude, but 'relieving oneself' has multiple meanings here, and I would say more often it is not related to poo.

Comment: @agweber I've personally never heard the phrase used with that particular euphemistic meaning (East coast U.S.), although it's not surprising that it might exist, given that the phrases operates by omitting the *thing of which* the person was relieved.

Comment: While I've certainly heard it used to mean a few different things, it's also worth noting that in British English, "relieving oneself" almost always means urinating rather than any other bodily function.

Comment: @scottishwildcat I cannot really speak to this but I believe the same is true for US English as well.

Answer (score 16):

The phrase "morning constitutional" is ambiguously used to mean either a morning walk, or a morning "dump". So "After his morning constitutional..."

Another possibility: "After spending some time on the throne..."

Comment: Awesome!!! the first one sounds soooo official :D

Comment: In what region(s) is this spoken? I would understand it to mean "a central physical activity of the morning", but would not necessarily associate with a "dump" without further context.

Comment: I wouldn't even associate it with a morning exercise.  I'd probably have to do a quick google - and even then if it can mean both I'd need extra context.  South Central and South Eastern U.S.A.

Comment: ***Midwest US weighing in*** - though not so common now, when I was growing up, mostly men had their morning "constitutional" in the bathroom. :-)

Comment: Yes, I'll admit that it's an old-fashioned usage -- but that's part of its charm :)

Comment: ***England here.*** I’m only familiar with the *walk* meaning, although I could easily imagine picking up the toilet meaning from context.

Answer (score 10):

Unless one is accounting for his activities to his doctor in which case he'd say he had a bowel movement at 9:00 AM today, it would probably suffice to say any of the following:

> **He made a pit stop**
>
> **He took a bathroom break**
>
> **He visited the men's room**
>
> **He went to the bathroom**

All of these are acceptable in mixed company, though they do tend to fall under the category of TMI (too much information) - and none clearly differentiate between urinating and defecating.

Comment: Any solution to this question involves TMI if it's at all direct. "Step out" is as direct a reference as I've heard, with "step down the hall/down the corridor/away" close behind. Usage: If anyone needs to step out during the meeting, simply do so. (Meaning, "If anyone needs to tend to personal business of any sort during the meeting, don't announce it. Simply leave quietly, go to the appropriate location, and return quietly when you are done.")

Answer (score 9):

As apsillers notes, "doing one's business" works in English. I think you could even use "business" directly in your fill-in-the-blank, especially if you put it in double-quotes to indicate its euphemistic nature:

> After his morning "business," Joe headed out for a coffee.

A little more verbose, but another common option for politely referring to the act is to refer to time spent in the bathroom:

> Joe took a few minutes in the bathroom, and then he headed out for a coffee.

FWIW, I don't think I'd ever use "constitutional" in the way that Ernest did.

Answer (score 8):

We Brits, for whatever reasons, don't seem to like to discuss the formalities of urination and defecation.

In fact, we are so afraid to discuss these acts that we have given them numbers.

Having a wee is "going for a [***number one***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/number+one?s=t)" whilst having a poo is "going for a [***number two***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/number+two)".

You could quite easily get away with the perfectly non-vulgar:

> After having his number two this morning, he...

Comment: While these are both pretty common in spoken english, I don't think I've ever seen them used in even slightly formal writing, so they might not be a good choice here.

Comment: I agree.  There are only a few cases in Google books where it appears but the OP did say "as long as you can say it at lunch".

Comment: Do you _have_ number 2s? I tend to _do_ them.

Comment: @terdon I've heard both.  And I've certainly heard "I'm going to have a dump".

Comment: Huh, OK, I would _take_ a dump.

Answer (score 2):

It is slightly vulgar but an expression that is similar to the German one you are familiar with, and common among friends is to say one 'dropped a load'.

```
Every morning after dropping a load, John...

I just dropped a serious load! Do not go in there!
```

The term 'relieved' is the most common and politically correct way of referring to the activity of one defecating.

```
Every morning after relieving himself, John...
```

Comment: Though in British English, "relieving himself" would generally indicate urination rather than defecation.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

> After finishing his breakfast, Martin **released a load** and brushed his
>   teeth.

or

> After finishing his breakfast, Martin **did away with an intestinal dragon** and brushed his teeth thereafter.

or

> After finishing his breakfast, Martin **ferociously had his way with the toilet** and brushed his teeth afterward.

or

> After finishing his breakfast, Martin **voided a faecal contract** and brushed his teeth shortly after.

Why not?

Comment: These are all fun fanciful ways to put it; they’re not common, neutral phrases for the act, though.

Comment: I'm glad they were at least enjoyed!

Comment: **had his way with** has other meanings, and caused a smile to appear as I envisioned something entirely different

Answer (score 2):

My English father would say he was "going to see a man about a dog".  I don't think that would work with an American audience.

Comment: An American (or _this_ American anyway) would think your father was going to urinate.

Comment: I always heard "going to see a man about a dog" as an excuse for leaving the house (GenAmE/Southern AmE)

Comment: Seeing a man about a dog is in American use, but old fashioned, to mean "I'm off to do shit, and you don't need to know what." Here, shit represents all manner of activities ... that I won't be detailing.

Answer (score 2):

*Dump* is a perfectly good word for this and it is not (very) vulgar. It's not refined either but can be used in relatively polite conversation (inasmuch as you can *have* a polite conversation when discussing the subject at hand):

[Definition source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dump)

> 4. informal an act of defecation.

So, you could say

> After his morning *dump*...

It is not the most polite of terms, but it is not as vulgar as all that either. Similarly, you could use [*crap*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crap):

> After his morning *crap*...

Again, it is not a particularly refined or polite word but it is not really vulgar as such either. As you can see in the Ngram below, while the vulgar *shit* is the most common, both *dump* and *crap* are also used:

[image]

Comment: Nice graph. There sure was a lot of defecation going on in 1914. I wonder why.

Comment: @n00b yes, especially considering how famously constipated the Victorians were.

Comment: @n00b Probably the soldiers in the trenches in WW1.

Comment: @terdon 1914 was 13 years after the reign of Victoria.

Comment: @Greybeard, I try not to let historical accuracy get in the way of a bad joke.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great phrase in the book "2001: A Space Odyssey" which is both very polite and clear.
It talks about an astronaut "attending to his toilet." (I can't find an online copy to link, and I don't have a copy on hand to cite a page number.)

This is respectful and euphemistic without being crass or embarrassing.

If there is a concern about ambiguity, and it's important to reference defecation in contrast to urination, the most polite way is to call it a "bowel movement."

"In the morning, after his bowel movement..." or "...after he had moved his bowels..."

it's polite, acceptable and specific to the act.

Answer (score 1):

Of interest is that the act of going to the bathroom to urinate or defecate  is often expressed as "going to the little boys'/girls' room",especially when in a public place.I suppose this betrays the speaker's embarrassment about bodily functions,as opposed to little children,who are not yet socialized.